# PHP mkdir() permissions

Tags: php, apache, mkdir

I have a Linux server with appache as the web server. In my PHP script I am making directories with `0777` mode. the code is pretty simple as follows:

```
mkdir($path,0777)
```

when I run this script and go to my server file manager, the folder is there but the permission assigned to that folder is 0755. I can't figure out why this is happening!! when the folder is created the user column has apache in it but the permission is 0755.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should try with the [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php)

```
$old = umask(0); 
mkdir($path,0777); 
umask($old);
```

Comment: thanks! solved the problem...but still confused why was my script nt able to create 777 folder permission?

Comment: @Salmanmahmood: This is something should be understand in Linux http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html just a link for your reference

Comment: Normally, umask is 022, which means to ignore any group or other write permissions. So if the permissions requested are 0777, then the permissions granted are 0777 - 022 = 0755.

Comment: Changing umask is not the safest way to do this. The approach suggested by Kart Funai here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878810/3153786 is _safer_

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
chmod ( string $filename , int $mode )
```

See if that can fix the permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apache might not have the permissions to change this. What you can do is. Make sure that apache is running in the same group as your current files group. Then apache will be able to make changes to that file. You can change you apache group in this apache config. Or the easiest way is to change the entire project user to be the apache user. Then apache can make w.e changes it wants.

go to the file from your server and type ls -al and look at the user and group

Answer (score 0):

Could be your umask:

```
<?php
$old = umask(0);
mkdir($dir,0777);
mask($old);
?>
```