# Creating folder in PHP with permissions 755 not working

Tags: php, mamp, file-permissions

When I create a folder in PHP (on my local server running MAMP in OSX), it's not setting the permissions of the folder correctly. For example, I would like the folder to be 755 when created. Here's my syntax:

```
mkdir($folder, 0755);
```

The folder gets created but the permissions look like this:

```
dr----x--x
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878784/php-mkdir-permissions)

Answer (score 4):

There're several comments in the manual that warn about current mask, [e.g.](https://www.php.net/mkdir#1207):

> The mode on your directory is affected by your current umask.  It will
> end up having ( and (not )).  If you want to create
> one that is publicly readable, do something like this:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $oldumask = umask(0);
> mkdir('mydir', 0777); // or even 01777 so you get the sticky bit set
> umask($oldumask);
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [mkdir manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) (emfasis mine):

> Note that you probably want to specify the mode as an octal number,
>   which means it should have a leading zero. **The mode is also modified
>   by the current umask, which you can change using umask()**.

So check [umask](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) also.

Comment: referring to a manual and copying the content from there is not an answer

Comment: Though you are right, I was giving the approach to the solution (the op's problem is related to umask, I just was stating that this problem is explained in the manual)

Comment: No idea if there was a previous version but this answer looks fine for me; probably better than mine (which I composed before I saw this), since it points out actual documentation rather than user comments.

Comment: Thankgs @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I upvoted yours because it gives the op a quick solution :-)

Comment: Copying from a manual is certainly a valid answer if it provides all of the information needed to solve the problem, but you've not really done that in this case. If you believe `umask` will fix OPs issue, you need to include information about `umask` in the answer, otherwise this is a "link only answer".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.