# Difficulty while deleting dynamically generated folder

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Recently I am working on a project in which a folder is dynamically generated by php. But this folder is not getting deleted it says "Unable to trash file". I found out that the user have changed. It is shown below. Please someone help. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: This needs much more context. The owner of the directory is `www-data`, because that's the user that Apache is running as, and it's Apache creating the directory. How are you attempting to delete the file? Through some other PHP code? What says "Unable to trash file"? Where is that error message appearing?

Comment: I am manually trying to delete the folder. I am pretty new to Linux .

Comment: How can I change the user to jharvard?

Comment: sudo chown jharvard:students file (and do not forget the -R  for a directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to delete the file as a one-off while you're developing, you should be able to do (on the terminal):

```
sudo rm -R <filename>
```

`sudo` is a command that temporarily gives you super-user access, and will therefore allow you to delete the file, even though you don't own it. If you get an error saying that you don't have `sudo` access, then you have a problem; you'll need to speak to whoever is responsible for administering that server.

The `-R` means 'recursively', i.e. it will delete the contents of the directory and then the directory itself.

Comment: How will I change the user to jharvard and group to students??

Comment: If you need to change the user you can do `sudo chown jharvard:students <filename>`, but if all you're going to do is delete it, then you just need the `sudo rm` command I mentioned in my answer. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this issue in future, you should look at a code, where `mkdir` takes place and check for its permissions argument.

The other thing that might help you is [umask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878836/3676230).

As of MTroy's comment on sudo: you should open up terminal window and do the following:

`cd ~/vhosts/final/public
sudo chown jharvard:students -r name_of_directory_to_be_claimed`

or

`sudo rm -r name_of_directory_to_be_deleted' to delete it

then it will ask for your su-password (Hope you have one :) )

As a bad option, there's Apache's setting for user from whom it have to work.

(It was supposed to be a comment, but I have low rep)